# Replace iwgetid with iw

Tags: shell, wifi, iw

I just get back a script to display the wifi connection on my desktop manager.
But this one is using `iwgetid` :

```
[[ -z "$(iwgetid -r)" ]] || echo "$(iwgetid -r)"
```

But `iwgetid` is depreciated and I didn't even see it inside Gentoo main repository. So I'm searching to replace the line above with `iw`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iwgetid -r` is a powerful command because you don't need to set the interface name, it can be replaced with the following **line** :

```
iw dev <interface> link | awk '/SSID/{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more simple and quick command you can use :

```
iw <interface> link|grep SSID | awk '{print '$2'}'|sed -u -e 's/SSID: //'
```

Comment: I didn't look into it too much right now, but seems like their is some special character in your answer which make the json using the answer fail.

Answer (score 0):

-You must be referring to this difference here is that if we use only we will have only the first name of the network if it is composed and not the full name, as in these examples.

```
 iw <interface> link | grep SSID | awk '{print $2}'
```

- Here you have only the 1st. name.

```
 iw <interface> link | grep SSID | awk '{print '$2'}'
```

- So you get the full name even if it is composed.

The rest of the code just removes the "SSID:" indication from the answer, making it simpler.

```
 iw <interface> link | grep SSID | awk '{print '$2'}' | sed -u -e 's/SSID: //'
```